# Почему масонри пропускает пустые места?

Tags: javascript

выложил этот блок на хостинг ,не может же это быть из-за сетки бутстрап,
а на остальных вкалдках по левой стороне распологает блоки
вот так два раза ее инициализирую при загрузке и при переключении вкладок

```
    $('.gallery-row.grid').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.gallery-full'
    });
```

```
$('.gallery-row.grid').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.gallery-full'
    });
$('.gallery-sortable').each(function(){
    var $that=$(this);
    var $filterType=$(this).find('.gallery-filter > ul > li.active > a').attr('data-type');
    var $holder=$(this).find('.gallery-list .gallery-row');
    var $data=$holder;
    $(this).find('.gallery-filter ul li a').on('click',function(e){
        $that.find('.gallery-filter ul li').removeClass('active');
        
        
        var $filterType=$(this).attr('data-type');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        var $filteredData;
        
        if( $filterType=="uslugi" ){
            $filteredData=$data.find('.gallery-full[data-type=all-dor-rab], .gallery-full[data-type=all-razmetka], .gallery-full[data-type=all-arenda], .gallery-full[data-type=all-installation]');
            $('.gallery-link-menu').slideUp();
            $('.gallery-link-menu').has('a[data-type=all-dor-rab]').slideDown();
            $('.gallery-link-menu').has('a[data-type=all-razmetka]').slideDown().siblings().has('a[data-type=all-arenda]').slideDown().siblings().has('a[data-type=all-installation]').slideDown();


        }
        else if($filterType=="orders"){
            $filteredData=$data.find('.only-orders');
            $('.gallery-link-menu').slideUp();
            $('.gallery-goods').slideDown();
        }
        else if($filterType=='all'){
            $filteredData=$data.find('.gallery-full');
            $('.gallery-link-menu').slideDown();
        }
        else{
            $filteredData=$data.find('.gallery-full[data-type='+$filterType+']');
        }
        /*$holder.quicksand($filteredData,{duration:0,useScaling:true,easing:'easeInOutQuad'});*/
        $holder.find(".gallery-full").hide();
        $filteredData.show();
        $('.gallery-row.grid').masonry({
            itemSelector: '.gallery-full',

        });
        return false;
        
    });

});
```

http://genrich.ru/masonri_not_working/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавил настройку columnWidth: 200, слегка поменялась ситуация ,но правильно все равно не работает